# Exporting attribute table to CSV via pure Python in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, export, csv

I would like to use pure Python to export the attribute table as csv. For the variable data, I need a list that will read the whole attribute table. Is that possible?

```py
import csv

layer = iface.activeLayer()
header = [field.name() for field in layer.fields()]
print(header)
data = [
    #Can I get the attribute table of the active layer here as a list
]

with open('//home/lissiklaus/Downloads/tmp/csv/countries.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    # write the header
    writer.writerow(header)

    # write multiple rows
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`.getFeatures()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorDataProvider.html#ab82526fc3df773e094d035a832dcbdf5) to iterate over each feature
and [`.attributes()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeature.html#a5a473f89868c234d53cea67504cd2f2e) to fetch each feature's attributes:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
fieldnames = [field.name() for field in layer.fields()] #If you need the fieldnames

attributes = []
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    attrs = f.attributes()
    #attrs is a list of current features attributes, for example 
    #[1, 561, 'Järnvägsstation', 0.0, 'Riksgränsen', NULL, '2012-03-29 12:56']
    attributes.append(attrs)

#attributes is now a list of lists:
#attributes[:2]
#[[1, 561, 'Järnvägsstation', 0.0, 'Riksgränsen', NULL, '2012-03-29 12:56'], 
# [2, 561, 'Järnvägsstation', 0.0, 'Katterjåkk', NULL, '2012-03-29 12:56']]

print("Done")
```

[image]

Comment: I prefer pure python because i later use LibreOffice-Base to establish  a database-connection and create pivot evaluations in calc. only with python do the numeric properties of certain fields remain in lo-base.

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

```py
import csv

outFolder = r'/home/lissiklaus/Downloads/tmp/csv/'
filename = 'countries.csv'
outPath = f"{outFolder}{filename}"

layer = iface.activeLayer()
header = [field.name() for field in layer.fields()]

myFeatures = layer.getFeatures()
data = [f for f in myFeatures]

with open(outPath, 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    # write the header
    writer.writerow(header)

    # write multiple rows
    writer.writerows(data)
```